# How to define final classvar variable in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.8, python-typing

As you can see in [PEP 526](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0526) we can define static variable class with ClassVar word. like below

```
class Starship:
    stats: ClassVar[dict[str, int]] = {} # class variable
    damage: int = 10                     # instance variable
```

And another typing feature as you can see in [PEP 591](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0591) we can define constant (readonly) variable with Final word, like below

```
class Connection:
    TIMEOUT: Final[int] = 10
```

My question is how to combine these two words to say my class static variable is Final?

for example is below code is valid?

```
class Connection:
    TIMEOUT: Final[ClassVar[int]] = 10
```

Comment: Just to make that clear: a type annotation does not define a name as a type, it documents it as a type.

Comment: What is meaning of that? please more explain @KlausD.

Comment: @sorosh_sabz the point, I believe, is that these are *type annotations*, but at runtime, these will not be enforced in any way (unless you write code that enforces them, or use a library that does that). For example, the following code works just fine `x: str = 42`

Comment: Type enforcement is a declared non-goal of type annotations.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

From [PEP-591](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0591/):

> Type checkers should infer a final attribute that is initialized in a
> class body as being a class variable. Variables should not be
> annotated with both ClassVar and Final.

So you ca just use:

```
class Connection:
    TIMEOUT: Final[int] = 10
```

Comment: In the current Python versions it is not even allowed to combine the two typing qualifiers. It will cause runtime error if you do not disable evaluation of annotations by using `from __future__ import annotations` --- Example: `class MyClass: x: Final[ClassVar[int]] = 1` ---> `TypeError: typing.ClassVar[int] is not valid as type argument` --- or when reversed: `TypeError: typing.Final[int] is not valid as type argument` --- mypy shows this error message: `error: Variable should not be annotated with both ClassVar and Final`

Comment: Marking the class variable with just `typing.Final` to indicate that the field is constant and can't be changed, however some libraries can't still handle Final class variable annotations properly. One such use case is `auto_attribs=True` in `attr.s` https://www.attrs.org/en/stable/api-attr.html#attr.s. This seems to be a defect in the library itself though.

Comment: Update: Python 3.13.0a5 (pr 116096) supports arbitrary nesting of Final/ClassVar/Annotation within each other. This is a runtime allowance; until a typing spec is changed, nothing has changed in the dataclass behavior (so the only well-treated runtime form is `ClassVar[Final[T]]`)